# Pull-up resistors needed between DS3231 and AHT10?

Tags: arduino, i2c, temperature, rtc

I'm trying to create a datalogger using DS3231, AHT10, ESP-01 and MicroSD Module. So far I noticed that the AHT10 is returning wrong fixed readings: -50 for temperature and 0 for humidity. When tested separately the AHT10 works fine, so I think the problem is when sharing the SDA/SCL with the DS3231.

Do I need to insert pull-up resistors? If yes, I don't how do this, since the AHT uses 3.3V and DS3231 uses 5V.

Edit: I changed both components to 3.3V, since they can handle it. Also, I changed the AHT10.h to Adafruit_AHTX0.h and everything worked.

Comment: Links to the datasheets, please.

Comment: Are you using the chips yourself or some bought modules? Are you sure the 5V module does not internally use 3.3V?

Comment: Hello. I read the ds3231 datasheet and saw that it works with 3.3V too. Unfortunately the problem with AHT10 readings remains and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [datasheet](https://wiki.liutyi.info/display/ARDUINO/AHT10?preview=/30507639/30507715/Aosong_AHT10_en_draft_0c.pdf) it looks like the AHT10 I2C pins are not 5V tolerant, so you can't share the I2C bus with the DS3231. If you haven't already damaged the sensor by doing so, you will eventually. Without a microcontroller datasheet its unclear what your next step should be, but look into a bi-directional I2C level shifter if your MCU only has one I2C bus.

Edit: Just looked at the DS3231 datasheet and it can be supplied with 3.3V. Is there any reason why you are using 5V instead?

Comment: Hello, InBedded16. Actually I read on the description where I bought this module that the supply was between 4.5V and 5.5V. My mistake. But once I changed the supply, the issue with the AHT10 remains (weird readings) and when I test only this sensor, it works fine. But thanks for the help.